# Use variable inside setAttribute()

Tags: javascript

Just trying to use setAttribute() with an easy example. Code works well when using plain text, but whenever I try to use a variable stops working:

```js
function getImageRoute(link) {
    var element_link = document.getElementById('highlight__link');
    element_link.setAttribute('href', link);
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = link;
}
```

```html
<a style="width: 100%;height: 100%;display: flex" id="highlight__link" href="https://www.google.es">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
  </div>
</a>

<div onclick="getImageRoute('https://justaroute.com');" style="width: 20%;padding: 5px;" class="highlight__wrap-item">
  <div class="news-block__item-thumb-wrap" >
    <h1>Click</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not working, what variable are you referring to? `element_link`? `link`?

Comment: No apparent reason why this should not work. Please provide proper [mre]s when you ask about issues like this - currently we can’t tell how you are calling that function, so we can not tell whether you perhaps messed things up in that part, either.

Comment: And FYI, using `setAttribute` is over the top in most cases anyway. `element_link.href = link;` would achieve the same thing here.

Comment: If it doesn't work using a variable then you are likely not passing the right value when calling `getImageRoute`.

Comment: @luk2302 `link` variable is not working. The value is correct, but somehow when using it inside setAttribute it does not work.

@CBroe Tried that way too, but does not work. Added a little example

Comment: You need to elaborate on "does not work." Be specific. Are you getting an error? Is the link not redirecting you? Is the variable undefined? The snippet you posted works perfectly.

Comment: As @Rojo says, the example seems to work. At least, it does what I would expect it to do.

Comment: @Rojo there is no error, it just does not work when using a variable...it does work if I use plain text instead a variable. Apparently it's ok, but href is not modified.

Comment: You need to post your exact code. You probably have a typo. The snippet you posted is working; I can click the link.